# Airflow: connection is not being created when using environment variables

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to create a Mongo connection (other than default) without using the Airflow UI.

I read from the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables):

> Connections in Airflow pipelines can be created using environment
>   variables. The environment variable needs to have a prefix of
>   AIRFLOW_CONN_ for Airflow with the value in a URI format to use the
>   connection properly.
>
> When referencing the connection in the Airflow pipeline, the conn_id
>   should be the name of the variable without the prefix. For example, if
>   the conn_id is named postgres_master the environment variable should
>   be named AIRFLOW_CONN_POSTGRES_MASTER (note that the environment
>   variable must be all uppercase).

I tried to apply this when using the [Puckel docker image](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow).

This is a docker compose using that image:

```
version: '2.1'
 services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.6
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
            - AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MONGO=mongodb://mongo:27017
        volumes:
            - ./src/:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

Note the line `AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_MONGO=mongodb://mongo:27017` where I'm passing the environment variable as the Airflow documentation suggests.

Problem here is that there is no `my_mongo` connection created when I'm listing the connections in the UI.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The connection won't be listed in the UI when you create it with environment variable.

**Reason**:

- Airflow supports the creation of connections via Environment variable for ad-hoc jobs in the DAGs
- The connection in the UI are actually saved in the DB and retrieved from it. The ones created by Env vars are not stored in DB

**How do I test my connection?**

- Create a sample DAG and use your connection to run a sample job. It should work fine.

Comment: Yes, I found that reading an issue in the Puckel site. I have already answered myself, but I will choose your answer since it is better explained.

Answer (score 1):

I read a [Puckel issue](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/238) where they mention that the connection is created, but is not showed in the UI. I tested it and in fact the connection works when used in a DAG.